# Convert meters to latitude and longitude

Tags: latitude-longitude

I have a field site. I know the coordinates of the center of the field site and that the site is 350 meters by 500 meters. Is there a formula or program that I can use to find the coordinates of the borders of my site? Most of what I've found is not accurate enough for my purposes. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Look into using the Havesine formula.

Comment: What have you found and why is it not accurate enough? How much accuracy do you need?

Comment: I found this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142326/calculating-longitude-length-in-miles It's off by 0.2 miles which is too much for my small site.

Comment: I think the Haversine formula gives the distance between two points, which isn't quite what I need. I have one point and the distance, but I need to find the second point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Convert your coordinates to a UTM (simple arithmetic transformation)
2. Convert to lat/long:

Here is open-source JavaScript code (link to github in article):

https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-utm-mgrs.html

Comment: Thank you, I think this is just what I needed!